# Elm, how to get current time and post it to server

Tags: time, elm, elm-architecture

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38361002/1243435) and [its helpful Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/jYds844LyMa1) I now have an idea of how we get the current time in Elm 0.18.

**I want to get the current time and then post it in JSON to my server. I already have a POST working with a hardcoded timestamp, but I just don't see how to get the current time and then include it in the JSON I am POSTing.**

My guess is that I need to chain a couple of commands (get current time, make a POST to server).

[I have also read [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39628761/1243435) which shows how you can run a few commands in a row by directly calling the `update` function, which sounds like a nice idea but I am not sure if it is what I need for my situation.]

### Experiment ([edit] perhaps more of a distraction than was intended)

In order to get my head around this I thought I would try to solve a similar problem that I can more easily set up in Ellie.

In [the original Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/jYds844LyMa1) the current time is gotten, updated into the model, and then the view function shows it.

In [my version](https://ellie-app.com/XZ7NPq9NPxa1) I wanted this to be a two-step process and therefore have grown the model to be a `Maybe Float` for the time and a `String` message. The `view` function shows the message string and a button -- the plan is that when the button is pressed it tells the runtime to 'go get the current time and then copy it across into the message slot'.

If I can solve this problem then I feel like I can solve my original problem.

My Ellie does not do this yet. When you press the button the time is gotten and is put into the `time` slot in the `model`, but I do not know how to tell the runtime to '...now copy that time across into the message slot'. The `PutTimeInMessage` message is in place, but I don't know how to get it to run after the `GetCurrentTime` message/command.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code so far (it compiles), which you can [run here in Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/XZ7NPq9NPxa1):

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Time exposing (Time)
import Date
import Task


type alias Model =
    { time : Maybe Float
    , message : String
    }


type Msg
    = OnTime Time
    | GetCurrentTime
    | PutTimeInMessage


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        OnTime t ->
            ( { model | time = Just t }, Cmd.none )

        GetCurrentTime ->
            ( model, getTime )

        PutTimeInMessage ->
            case model.time of
                Nothing ->
                    ( model, Cmd.none )

                Just t ->
                    ( { model | message = toString t }, Cmd.none )


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div []
            [ button [ onClick GetCurrentTime ] [ Html.text "Get now time." ]
            ]
        , model.message |> Html.text
        ]


getTime : Cmd Msg
getTime =
    Time.now
        |> Task.perform OnTime


main =
    Html.program
        { init = ( Model Nothing "Empty message.", Cmd.none )
        , update = update
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = always Sub.none
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across an [SO which explained how to do a sequence of Http requests with `Task.andThen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51104668/1243435). Since I can see the type of `Time.now` is a `Task` I figured that I could adapt that example for my purposes if I use `Http.toTask`.

Below is the solution I came up with and [here it is in Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/Y9KSXB9wPba1):

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Http
import Json.Decode as JD
import Json.Encode as JE
import Task
import Time


type alias Model =
    { url : String
    }


type Msg
    = PostTimeToServer
    | PostDone (Result Http.Error String)


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        PostTimeToServer ->
            ( model, postTimeToServer model.url )

        PostDone _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div []
            [ button [ onClick PostTimeToServer ] [ Html.text "POST the current time." ]
            ]
        ]


postTimeToServer : String -> Cmd Msg
postTimeToServer url =
    let
        getTime =
            Time.now

        postTime t =
            JD.string
                |> Http.post url (JE.float t |> Http.jsonBody)
                |> Http.toTask

        request =
            getTime                                            <<-- Here is
                |> Task.andThen postTime                       <<-- the key bit.
    in
        Task.attempt PostDone request


main =
    Html.program
        { init = ( Model "url_here", Cmd.none )
        , update = update
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = always Sub.none
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, you can just update `message` field along with `time` field, when `OnTime` message is received. Thus, the whole `update` function is going to look like this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        OnTime t ->
            ( { model | time = Just t, message = toString t }, Cmd.none )

        GetCurrentTime ->
            ( model, getTime )
```

The `message` is set in `OnTime` action, because in the `GetCurrentTime` time is unknown and is known only after `getTime` function is perform and `OnTime` message is received.

If you still want to use a separate action for putting the `message`, then the following code is the option:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        OnTime t ->
            update PutTimeInMessage { model | time = Just t }

        GetCurrentTime ->
            ( model, getTime )

        PutTimeInMessage ->
            case model.time of
                Nothing ->
                    ( model, Cmd.none )

                Just t ->
                    ( { model | message = toString t }, Cmd.none )
```

But to be honest, the most preferable solution, would be just displaying the `time` in the view differently, so you don't need the `message` field (but probably I don't see the whole picture):

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div []
            [ button [ onClick GetCurrentTime ] [ Html.text "Get now time." ]
            ]
        , viewTime model.time
    ]

viewTime : Maybe Float -> Html Msg
viewTime time =
  case time of
    Nothing -> Html.text "Empty message."
    Just t -> Html.text (toString t)
```

Comment: This example with the message was contrived, just to help me get my head around the problem that I really want to solve the problem (getting the time and then including it in the JSON for a POST). Your second piece of code solves that problem, I think: the call to `update` is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Igor, I appreciate your answer but after a bit of work I found that it did not resolve my problem. I probably distracted you with my 'experimental question', since it was actually a bit too far away from my _real_ problem of  'get time and put it in the body of a POST'. After some more work I found that `Task.andThen` was the right solution for me. See my answer.